# SerialPort.Open sending a bunch of ones to Arduino before any SerialPort.Write call

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

I noticed some weird behavior on a program that sends messages to Arduino by the serial port and after putting a breakpoint on the first write I noticed the board seemed to be behaving as if it had already received a message at that point. I connected 8 LEDs to the board so I could light them up to see what byte value they were receiving and ran the following code:

.ino sketch:

```
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(19200);
    for(int i=22;i<30;i++){
        pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
    }
}

void loop(){
    if(Serial.available() > 0){
        for(int i=0;i<8;i++){
            digitalWrite(22+i, (Serial.peek() >> i) & 1);
        }
        delay(1000);
        Serial.read();
    }
}
```

C#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var port = new SerialPort(SerialPort.GetPortNames()[0])
    {
        BaudRate = 19200,
        StopBits = StopBits.One,
        Parity = Parity.None,
        Handshake = Handshake.None
    };
    port.Open();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    port.Write(new byte[] { 99 }, 0, 1);    //breakpoint here
}
```

When the code reaches the breakpoint, all 8 LEDs light up, so the arduino somehow received a byte with value 255, before I had called `port.Write()`. I repeated this experiment a few times, and got 7 LEDs to light up a couple times (so I got 7 one bits instead of 8), one time I even got a second byte with the C# code still in the breakpoint. After letting the C# code resume execution I get the expected 01100011 which is 99.

Weirdly, if I set the baud rate to the default 9600 (both on arduino and C#) this issue doesn't happen. But I've tried 19200, 57600 and 115200 and this weird behavior happens in all of them. However as mentioned before, after discarding these first 1 or 2 bytes, everything works as expected, so I'm pretty sure this isn't caused by a baud rate mismatch.

So while I can think of ways to work around this, I assume `port.Open()` shouldn't be behaving like this and there must be something I'm missing, and was hoping someone had any idea of what I could be doing wrong.

edit: As requested, my arduino is a mega ADK.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first. I don't think the fault lies in .NET's `SerialPort` library. We use it extensively -and it has many faults- but sending unwanted signals has never been one of them. You probably should check on the Arduino side whether there's actually data on the line, or if it's a false positive.

The doco for [Serial.available()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/available/) does not mention what its return value is when the line is empty; but the one for [Serial.peek()](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/peek/) specifically says it returns `-1` when no data is available. Since the return type for both functions are ***signed*** `int` and not `byte`, guess what the binary is for `-1`? Yup, all-ones.

I would suggest changing your `Serial.available()` check from `!= 0` to `> 0` to eliminate the possibility of `-1` being caught as a false positive.

---

PS. Yes it's really annoying that there's no way to tell (int)-1 from (byte)255.

PPS. I don't have an Arduino in hand atm to test. But if the above doesn't work, maybe mention which Arduino you're using to see if anyone else can help.

Comment: Interesting idea, I hadn't realized a right shifted -1 would also light up all the LEDs, but unfortunately that's not what's happening here and after changing the `!=` to `>` the issue persists.  The doc you linked does say it returns the number of bytes available to read, which is 0 if there are none. It also shows an example with `if(Serial.available())`, which wouldn't work if it returned -1 since any non zero value is equivalent to true in an if statement. I've also confirmed on the serial monitor of the ide that my arduino does return 0 in that function. My arduino is a mega ADK.

Comment: @Janilson, ah yeah I missed the example. Have you tried calling `port.DiscardOutBuffer()` immediately after Open() on the C# side?  Otherwise, depending on how your serial is connected, they could be legit electrical noise while setting up the line? What happens if you keep alternating between Open() and Close() with a delay in C#?

Comment: It could also be the USB-to-Serial chip on the board. If you have an external adapter, you could try the other 3 UART pins on the board.

Comment: `DiscardOutBuffer` doesn't help, tried a different computer (but same board) now and had the same issue. I've just tried remaking the basic C# write program using native win32 calls on C++ and it worked normally, so I'm actually getting more inclined to think there is indeed some bug in .net code instead of being a problem with the board. Perhaps I should've mentioned it earlier but I'm using .net 4.8, maybe I'll try it again with core/.NET6 later. I'm actually considering downloading the 4.8 source code and try to debug it to see if I find anything.

Comment: The plot thickens... I managed to replicate the issue in C++ now too... seems that when the `SetCommState` function from `winbase.h` is called is when those unintended bytes get written.

Comment: It's a bit hard to assign blame. The only way to minimise the variables are by using a direct comport on the PC, straight to a UART pin on the chip. As it stands, there's so many points of failure. On the windows side, there's the Arduino virtual comport driver; on the Mega ADK there's the external USB-to-serial chip. Then there's the Arduino serial driver that provides the static `Serial` class. Either way, when dealing with serial you would need a robust framing protocol that can tolerate rubbish, as it's very prone to noise. Especially RS232..

Comment: Actually, if you enjoy pain, you could try installing Wireshark and using its UsbPcap driver to snoop on the USB traffic. It would tell you if there was an actual traffic being sent on the USB level when opening the virtual comport. The challenge would be finding the right USB device in the haystack of traffic.

Comment: I think I've had enough pain thank you. Enough time has been spent on this wild goose chase, I'll just make some kind of custom handshake protocol before starting actual communications and call it a day.